# JQuery validation plugin require email in certain cases

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, email-validation, required

I have a member management page where the client wants a field to be always required and if the user is a member, then it must be an email address.  If the account is for an admin, it does not have to be an email.  My first thought was, "easy.  function() just like I do when a field is sometimes required."

I am using the JQuery validation plugin.  This is the line in question.

```
ename: { required: true, email: function() { var retVal = ($("#mem_rights").val() == 4); alert(retVal); return retVal; }},
```

The alert is debug code, and it shows that the function is evaluating correctly.  When I am on an admin page, it evaluates to false but I still get the error message next to the input box saying, "Please enter a valid email address" if I make the value a non email address.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no rule but `required` takes a dependency function or expression by default.

Here's one way you could do it by overwriting the default `email` rule (or adding one with a name of your own choosing) so that it takes a dependency function.

```
var oldEmail = $.validator.methods.email;

$.validator.addMethod("email", function(value, element, param) {
    return !param || oldEmail.call(this, value, element);
});

$("#test").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            email: {
                depends: function () {
                    return $("#require-email").is(":checked");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rvsDs/

If you're nervous about overwriting the default `email` rule (a valid concern), you could just name the new rule `conditionalemail` or something similar.

Comment: I did change the name of the custom method, but that did it.  Then I just added a message.  Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the `required` attribute can also be a [dependency expression](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression) or a [dependency callback](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-callback), which you can use to do conditional requires. You could probably write something like this:

```js
ename: {
  required: function(el) {
    return $("#mem_rights").val() == 4;
  }
}
```

Although if the value isn't changing, no need for the function, just evaluate an expression like so:

```js
ename: { required: ($("#mem_rights").val() == 4) }
```

Comment: It's not the required portion that is causing problems.  It's the email portion.